# python -v and python3 -V give different results

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyenv

python -v and python3 -V give different results

## Current status.

```
$ python -V
Python 3.10.10
```

```
$ python3 -V
Python 3.9.16
```

Output results will be different.

## What I did

Switched versions in pyenv.

```
$ pyenv global 3.10.10
```

## What I want to do.

I want both to be Python 3.10.10.
I've tried everything, but I wasn't sure how to do it.
I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to do it.

Comment: `python` and `python3` are just symbolic links, change them. do `ls -liah` in the directory of `which python` and you'll the links

Comment: /usr/local/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python3.9

Comment: and for the python3 ?

Comment: What should i do ?

Comment: where does python3 points ? I guess `/usr/bin/python3.10`
Do `rm /usr/local/bin/python` then `ln -s  /usr/bin/python3.10 /usr/local/bin/python`

Comment: $which python
/usr/local/bin/python

Comment: $which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3

Comment: @Tdayo It is possible you are in a directory with local `pyenv` setting. Have you tried `pyenv local --unset`?

Comment: @Tdayo On a closer look, your `which python` seems to indicate pyenv isn't even kicking in. If it does, it should point to the shims directory. Example, I expect `$which python` to return `/home/souser/.pyenv/shims/python`. So, double-check that you have run ALL of the install steps [here](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#getting-pyenv).